# Android Tab ico in API 16

Tags: android, api

I have an app with 4 tabs and icon images for each tab. I am using TabActivity and TabHost.

setIndicator ("Example", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabicon));

The app works fine with API 8 and when I have the following in the manifest file :

but when I explicitly put the targetSdkVersion="16" in the manifest, the tab icons are not showing.

How can I preserve the Tab icons without changing a bunch of code? Is there a Tab icon code sample I can follow for API 16?

thanks a bunch !!

Answer (score 0):

`TabActivity` and `TabHost` are deprecated in API 11.

Instead use the [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) with Tabs ([Example here](https://github.com/Leandros/ActionBar-with-Tabs)), for compatability with API versions lower than 11 use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com).

**Don't use old APIs anymore!**